# Pytest Github Action failed in Django REST API project

Tags: github, django-rest-framework, pytest, github-actions, pytest-django

I have updated my workflow action from simple `super-linter` to `PYTEST`. I get the following error in github

```
Run pipenv install --deploy --dev
ERROR: Pipfile not found! Aborting! Please ensure that the file exists and is located in your project root directory.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Super linter is really lazy and fails unnecessarily even if the code is correctly formatted?

I have not added any file in my project? Do I need to?

Comment: Could you share your project structure as well as the workflow implementation you used please?

Comment: https://github.com/iamahmedshahh/djangowallet

Comment: Super linter didn't required any modifications in my project? I haven't added anything in my project structure, I thought the .yml program will automatically check all the pushes, like super linter did. pretty new to this

Comment: It seems the problem isn't related to super linter, but to a **Pipfile** file missing in the working directory  (repository root) when you execute the `pipenv install --deploy --dev` command in the `Install dependencies` job.

Comment: I made it work just by adding a **Pipfile** with a `touch Pipfile` command, as you see here: [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/djangowallet/runs/5395849081?check_suite_focus=true) and [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/djangowallet/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow.yml). Let me know if it resolved your issue.

Comment: so I should just add this command through VSCode terminal? Your GitHub profile is just brilliant.

Comment: Yes, adding the **Pipfile** at the repository root should resolve your issue as well. Thanks :)

Comment: The touch command didnt work in vscode terminal, I just pasted your workflow file to mine

Comment: Your github is amazing maybe i can learn python from you xD, so this pytest action will check our code for errors or missing dependencies right?

Comment: For what I understood, your workflow only run your unit tests with pytest, it doesn't even use a linter.

Comment: You eventually add a step using the https://github.com/github/super-linter action in your workflow.

Comment: Can I add that within the same workflow file? Can you please do me a last favor and tell me which line should I add that? If possible? Would be thankful

Comment: You can add it as last step of your job. After everything that is already present in what you did.

Comment: Thanks mate, idk why people were pushing for pytest it seems useless if it doesn't check my code base

Comment: Gave you credits for the actions in readme many thanks, haven't tested linter yet cause it really is a headache, failing tests for line spaces and whatnot, much thanks